# SQL Server Import Wizard not showing Database selection

Tags: sql-server, import, wizard

It isn't there. I created a shortcut from the SSMS tasks import menu but now I can't select a database.

[Where is the DB selection?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzPg7.png)

Comment: No database shows up there in the space where your question mark is unless you use SQL Server Authentication.  Make sure you have the right server selected or entered, and then click the "Next" button.

Answer (score 4):

Oh crap, I just realized the box wasn't sized right and the database was hidden. Something about your answer prompted me to resize it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered. I have a laptop and an external monitor that is bigger than the laptop screen. I am extending the display and when I use the larger display for my work the rendering of the screens seems to use the smaller screen to determine what to show.

Go figure.